# conjugate function of log trace of matrix exponential

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Given an n-by-n real symmetric matrix X, define
$$e^X = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{X^k}{k!}$$
Derive the Fenchel conjugate of
$$f(X) = log(Tr(e^X))$$
as a function on n-by-n real symmetric matrices. Here Tr denotes the trace function.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the Fenchel conjugate of $f(X)$ is given by:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:f}\tag{1}
f^{*}(Y) = \sup_{X} X\circ Y - f(X). 
\end{equation}

It can be shown that $g(X) \overset{\text{def}}{=} X\circ Y - f(X)$ is a concave function in terms of $X$.
(Actually, you can use the second derivative of $f(X)$ with respect to $X$ to show that $f(X)$ is a convex function.)
To compute the supremum of $g(X)$, we take derivative of $g(X)$ with respect to $X$, we have
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
Y= \frac{(\exp X) }{\text{Tr} (\exp X) }. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Thus, $I\circ Y=  1$ and $y_{ii}>0$ for $1\le i\le n$.
Using the fact $\log (AB) =\log (A)  + \log (B) $ if $AB=BA$, it follows that
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:y}\tag{2}
Y = \frac{(\exp X) }{\exp f(X)} \implies \log Y + f(X) I  =  X. 
\end{equation}

Substitute \eqref{eq:y} into \eqref{eq:f}, we have

\begin{align}
\label{eq:f:final}
f^{*}(Y) & = (\log Y + f(X)  I  ) \circ Y - f(X)\notag \\
& = \log Y \circ Y + f(X)  I \circ Y - f(X) \notag\\
& = \log Y \circ Y. \tag*{using $I\circ Y=  1$.}
\end{align}

Comment: This is a very good answer!